# Vector and raster don't match

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, vector

I'm working with QGIS and I would like to match the vector and raster data from Natural Earth. I used the same coordinate system (EPSG:4326) but both layers don't match. I want to change the style of the vector layer with the raster one but I can't overlap both.

I'm using the coordinate system EPSG4326 WGS 84. I tried to assign a new coordinate to the Raster layer, but appears the "error 255"

What could be the problem?

[image: This is how my map looks like]

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to include the bounding envelopes of the two datasets and explain *exactly* how you "used the same CRS" (since that seems to be the problem)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! It looks like you have a coordinate system problem, see if any of the suggestions at https://ihatecoordinatesystems.com/ help.

Comment: Hi! I updated the information. Thank you all. It seams that I have a problem with the projection, but I don't know how to solve it. I want to merge both layers to create a different style combining both. I'm using the coordinate system EPSG4326 WGS 84. I tried to assign a new coordinate to the Raster layer, but appears the "error 255".

Comment: This problem is common using `EPSG:4326` when zoomed out (world level, showing the whole world). Does the problem persist if you zoom in to country level?